# Could not find a declaration file for module '@stripe/stripe-js'

Tags: node.js

./components/shared/Checkout.tsx:2:26
Type error: Could not find a declaration file for module '@stripe/stripe-js'. '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/dist/stripe.mjs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
There are types at '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.d.ts', but this result could not be resolved when respecting package.json "exports". The '@stripe/stripe-js' library may need to update its package.json or typings.
1 | import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

> 2 | import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
> |                          ^
> 3 |
> 4 | import { IEvent } from '@/lib/database/models/event.model';
> 5 | import { Button } from '../ui/button';
> Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

showing error in vercel because of this error.

please help me to fixed this. i created this application 1 week+ now i'm struggling with this

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `@stripe/stripe-js`:

```bash
npm remove @stripe/stripe-js
```

And install an older version by this command:

```bash
npm install @stripe/stripe-js@2.2.1
```